# Mejorar la performance de una colleccion con multiples registros

Tags: vb.net, linq, collectionjs

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
For Each Subitem In lstGastoResumen_Area
    Dim MesRealSub
    Dim MesPPTOSub

    MesRealSub = Aggregate y In lstGastoResumen Where y.Area = Subitem And y.Anio = Anio1 Into Sum(y.FebRealSoles)
    MesPPTOSub = Aggregate y In lstGastoResumen Where y.Area = Subitem And y.Anio = Anio1 Into Sum(y.FebPptoSoles)
Next
```

Donde `lstGastoResumen` es un hashset y contiene mas de 80,000 filas y `lstGastoResumen_Area` tiene 20 filas. Este codigo demora en ejecutarse 20 segundos.
Alguien podria indicarme como mejorar la performance?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo en tu código, el problema parece ser que siempre estás trabajando sobre la colección completa, por lo que estás haciendo el `where` dos veces en cada iteración, o sea 40 veces.

Linq permite por ejemplo agrupar los datos. Podrías primero agrupar por área y en ese momento ya filtrar por año, y luego trabajar sobre la nueva colección.

No conozco demasiado la sintaxis de VB.net, pero me refiero a algo así:

```
Dim lstGastoResumenByArea = From y In lstGastoResumen
                            Where y.Anio = Anio1
                            Group by Area = y.Area
For Each Subitem In lstGastoResumen_Area
    Dim MesRealSub = From gasto In lstGastoResumenByArea
                     Where gasto.Area = Subitem
                     Aggregate y In gasto.Area
                     Into Sum(y.FebRealSoles)
    Dim MesRealSub = From gasto In lstGastoResumenByArea
                     Where gasto.Area = Subitem
                     Aggregate y In gasto.Area
                     Into Sum(y.FebPptoSoles)
Next
```

De hecho la parte de

```
                 From gasto In lstGastoResumenByArea
                 Where gasto.Area = Subitem
```

la deberías poder hacer una sola vez guardando el resultado en otra variable.

Incluso tal vez se pueda mejorar aún más si la parte del `Aggregate` la haces en el `Group By`...

Más información (en inglés): [Group By Clause (Visual Basic)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/queries/group-by-clause)